# making module.exports conditional

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

I'm trying to import *react-native* into a file named *react-native.config.js* , but I get this error :

```
import typeof AccessibilityInfo from './Libraries/Components/AccessibilityInfo/AccessibilityInfo';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

here is the code I used :

```
  const rn = require('react-native');
  
  module.exports = {
    assets: ['./assets/fonts'],
    dependencies: {
      'react-native-video': {
        platforms: {
          android: {
            sourceDir: '../node_modules/react-native-video/android-exoplayer',
          },
        },
      },
    },
  };
```

I want to be able to use [React-Native`s Platform](https://reactnative.dev/docs/platform) to detect if the Device is running Android or AndroidTV . And for this purpose I want to know if making module.exports conditional is possible or not .
For example this code :

```
const rn = require('react-native');

module.exports = {
  assets: ['./assets/fonts'],
  dependencies: {
    'react-native-video': {
      platforms: {
        android: {
          sourceDir: rn.Platform.isTV
            ? '../node_modules/react-native-video/android-exoplayer'
            : '../node_modules/react-native-video/android',
        },
      },
    },
  },
};
```