# Detecting the device OS in react-native (without using the platform api)

Tags: android, react-native, android-tv

I'm trying to detect if the app is running on an android or androidTV , i cant use the [react-native's platform api](https://reactnative.dev/docs/platform) because of the issue i asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68216704/making-module-exports-conditional) .

Are there any other packages that let me do this ? or can i write it myself using javascript ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getDeviceType` helper from `react-native-device-info` https://github.com/react-native-device-info/react-native-device-info#getDeviceType

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { getDeviceType } from 'react-native-device-info';

const deviceType = getDeviceType();

const App = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{deviceType}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: `import typeof AccessibilityInfo from './Libraries/Components/AccessibilityInfo/AccessibilityInfo';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` i get this error while trying to import like this `const info = require('react-native-device-info');`

Comment: Are you use Expo or RN CLI?

Comment: i'm using RN CLI

Comment: what version of `react-native` package are you use?

Comment: react-native-tvos@^0.63.4-0

Comment: What device or emulator you get this error?

Comment: Maybe you forgot install library? `npm install --save react-native-device-info`

Comment: i installed it , seems to be a problem with packages that start with the name of "react-native"

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this will solve you're specific use case but you can have specific files for each platform by specifying it in the filename:

```
index.android.js
index.ios.js
```

React native will do the work of choosing which file to use based on the platform.

Comment: I want to specify for android and androidtv

Comment: Got it my bad just re read the question, you will need to look into creating your own NativeModule that can detect whether its android or androidTV, check https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android

Answer (score 0):

Try Platform module from React Native

```
import { Platform } from "react-native"

isTV === Platform.constants.uiMode === "tv"
```

https://reactnative.dev/docs/platform#properties